# PySpark sorting array of struct

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

This is a dummy sample of my dataframe

```
data = [
    [3273, "city y", [["ids", 27], ["smf", 13], ["tlk", 35], ["thr", 24]]],
    [3213, "city x", [["smf", 23], ["tlk", 15], ["ids", 17], ["thr", 34]]],
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    data, "city_id:long, city_name:string, cel:array<struct<carr:string, subs:int>>"
)
df.show(2, False)

+-------+---------+--------------------------------------------+
|city_id|city_name|cel                                         |
+-------+---------+--------------------------------------------+
|3273   |city y   |[[ids, 27], [smf, 13], [tlk, 35], [thr, 24]]|
|3213   |city x   |[[smf, 23], [tlk, 15], [ids, 17], [thr, 34]]|
+-------+---------+--------------------------------------------+
```

I need to descendingly sort the array of column ***cel*** based on its ***subs*** value. It would be like this

```
+-------+---------+--------------------------------------------+
|city_id|city_name|cel                                         |
+-------+---------+--------------------------------------------+
|3273   |city y   |[[tlk, 35], [ids, 27], [thr, 24], [smf, 13]]|
|3213   |city x   |[[thr, 34], [smf, 23], [ids, 17], [tlk, 15]]|
+-------+---------+--------------------------------------------+
```

Is there a way of doing it without using an UDF if possible? thanks

I am using spark version 2.4.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it using some SQL lambda functions :

```py
df = df.withColumn(
    "cel",
    F.expr(
        "reverse(array_sort(transform(cel,x->struct(x['subs'] as subs,x['carr'] as carr))))"
    ),
)

df.show()
+-------+---------+--------------------------------------------+
|city_id|city_name|cel                                         |
+-------+---------+--------------------------------------------+
|3273   |city y   |[[35, tlk], [27, ids], [24, thr], [13, smf]]|
|3213   |city x   |[[34, thr], [23, smf], [17, ids], [15, tlk]]|
+-------+---------+--------------------------------------------+

df.printSchema()
root
 |-- city_id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- city_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- cel: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- subs: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- carr: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Its interesting to see spark has two separate functions (`array_sort` and `sort_array`) for sorting an array, of course one places the null ahead and other doesnot, may be they should merge both and keep null value preference as an arg. Any idea if such requests are raised? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: @anky Yep, indeed. Array manipulation functiond are new in 2.4. They are reflected in SQL api. but `sort_array` existed previously. They kept it for back compatibility.

Comment: @Steven Thank you so much, works as expected. For my case the order of the struct doesn't matter so all good.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [sort_array()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/sql/index.html#sort_array) to sort an array column. But in case of `array<struct>` column this will sort the first column. So we can swap the columns using transform function before using sort_array().

```
>>> df.withColumn('cel', expr('sort_array(transform(cel, c-> struct(c.subs, c.carr)), False)')).show(truncate=False)
+-------+---------+--------------------------------------------+
|city_id|city_name|cel                                         |
+-------+---------+--------------------------------------------+
|3273   |city y   |[{35, tlk}, {27, ids}, {24, thr}, {13, smf}]|
|3213   |city x   |[{34, thr}, {23, smf}, {17, ids}, {15, tlk}]|
+-------+---------+--------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Its interesting to see spark has two separate functions for sorting an array, of course one places the null ahead and other doesnot, may be they should merge both and keep null value preference as an arg.

Comment: @Mohana Thank you for your answer. Initially, dereferencing using `c.subs` threw an error but when I changed it to `c["subs"]` then this code gave the same result as Steven's code.

Comment: Oh. But it worked for me with spark version 3.1.2

Comment: @anky. Yes they could merge both into single function. Using sort_array we can order in both ascending and descending order but with array_sort only ascending is possible.